# Converting items in listview too string. VB

Tags: vb.net, listview

So im trying to find a code that is converting items from a listview In VB.net too a string that then can be saved into a .txt but i have that bit done i just need help with the converting, Any code that i can follow or use?

Comment: Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask].  Each ListViewItem has a .Text property for what you want.  If you also/actually need SubItems, read the link and update your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [SubItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of each ListViewItem in the ListView.  Note that the first entry in the SubItems collection is the main ListViewItem text:

> The first subitem in the ListViewItem.ListViewSubItemCollection is
>   always the item that owns the subitems.

So something like:

```
    Using SW As New System.IO.StreamWriter("someFile.txt")
        Dim line As String
        Dim values As New List(Of String)
        For Each LVI As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
            values.Clear()
            For i As Integer = 0 To LVI.SubItems.Count - 1
                values.Add(LVI.SubItems(i).Text)
            Next
            line = String.Join(",", values.ToArray)
            SW.WriteLine(line)
        Next
    End Using
```

Comment: Theanks for that, It really was bugging me :D!